# SwiftUI Text view not using localized stringsdict file

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Given this view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let count = 1
    var body: some View {
        Text("There are \(count) light(s)")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

And this `Localizable.stringsdict`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>There are %ld light(s)</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@LIGHT_STRING@</string>
        <key>LIGHT_STRING</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>ld</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>There is one light</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>There are %ld lights</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I would expect the view to say "There is one light". But instead, it says "There are 1 light(s)".

What am I missing?

---

### Attempted Troubleshooting

If I add this function:

```
    func tr(_ key: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
        let format = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
        return String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
    }
```

And then use this syntax:

```
        Text(tr("There are %ld light(s)", 1))
            .padding()
```

Then I get the expected result. So I think the problem is something with the `Text` view not generating the correct key (as opposed to something wrong with my stringsdict file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, got it working. I had to double check a few things:

1. Get the correct key for the dict file by typing `po LocalizedStringKey("There are \(count) light(s)")` in the debugger, which outputted the key `About to Update %lld Contact(s)` (I was using `%ld`).
2. Select the stringsdict file and click `Localize…` in the file inspector
3. Name the file `Localizable.stringsdict`